Lower bound on Krull dimension of a polynomial ring in one variable
I want to show that $\dim A[x]\ge \dim A+1$ for a (commutative with 1) ring $A$, where $\dim R$ is the Krull dimension of $R$, i.e. the length $n$ of the longest chain of prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_0\subsetneq\mathfrak p_1\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_2\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_n$ in $R$.
I think if we are given a chain in $A$ of length $\dim A=n$, say
$\mathfrak{p}_0\subsetneq\mathfrak p_1\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_2\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_n$ is a chain of prime ideals, we can consider the chain in $A[x]$:
$$\mathfrak{p}_0^e\subsetneq\mathfrak p_1^e\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_2^e\subsetneq\cdots\subsetneq\mathfrak{p}_n^e\subsetneq(\mathfrak{p}_n^e,x)$$
where the extensions are w.r.t. the map $A\to A[x]$. But I am unable to show that $\mathfrak p\subsetneq\mathfrak q$ in $A$ implies $\mathfrak p^e\subsetneq\mathfrak q^e$ in $A[x]$.  How can I show this?

Duplicate. Please use site search.

@MartinBrandenburg: I found several posts. All of them dismiss this as trivial. For example, this. This one just mentions the construction, not why it works.

$\mathfrak{p^e}$ is just the ideal of polynomials whose coefficients are all in $\mathfrak{p}$. This observation makes the strict inclusions pretty much obvious.

@Mark: Yeah, this is trivial. I missed it somehow. Thanks, you can perhaps post this as an answer.

It follows since $\mathfrak{p}^e = \mathfrak{p}[x]$, from which you can infer $\mathfrak{p}^e \cap A = \mathfrak{p}$. Hence, prime ideals of $A$ can be recovered from their extensions in $A[x]$.
